# How to access a form component from another (referenced) Project in visual C# 2013?

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, namespaces

I'm trying to change the text in a RichTextBox in my "Game" project from another "Engine" project in Visual Studio community 2013, which is already referenced by the "Game" project. Everything I've tried to access it does not bring up the RichTextBox via Intellisense, causes a redline, and the "Engine" project refuses to build.

From checking around the site and Google, I've tried making the RichTextBox static and a few other tricks, including one I came up with myself- making a third project and referencing the other two. All to no avail.

Here should be the important parts of the code I have now:

in Game.cs, I have the class public:

```
namespace Game
{
    public partial class Game : Form
    {
        ...  //All the code for the form
    }
}
```

in Game.Designer.cs I have the RichTextBox public and static:

```
namespace Game
{
    partial class Game
    {
        ... // All the other unimportant stuff
        public static System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtbMessages; //I've fixed the errors this caused in InitializeComponent() already
    }
}
```

Now from my "Engine" project, I'll try something like this (simplified but it shows what I'm trying to do):

```
using Game;

nameSpace Engine
{
    public class Monster
    {
        ... // Properties, Constructor, etc.

        public static bool IsDead(string name, int currentHP)
            if (currentHP <= 0)
            {
                Game.rtbMessages.Text += String.Format("You have killed {0}.{1}", name, Environment.NewLine);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I've only been learning C# and Object-Oriented programming for 3 weeks now using basic tutorials I've been able to find online, but from what I've learned I honestly don't know why this won't work. I tried adding a reference from "Engine" back to "Game", but I get an error saying this would create a circular dependency since "Game" already references "Engine".

Is this even possible? I'm starting to wonder.

Edit: I made the mistake of assuming "Project" was just the name VS used for namespace. The problem isn't that they're in different namespaces, but different projects. Hence the strikeouts.

Comment: "I've fixed the errors this caused in InitializeComponent() already" - can you specify what errors those were? Usually, you should never change anything in `*.Designer.cs`, as that file is entirely generated by WYSIWYG designers.

Comment: hmm hard to tell from your code, but there are a number of potential problems. 1: you have Game namesspace and Game Object, which can confuse intelisense 2: you are referenceing Games rich text box from the engine? just from the naming of the object I imagine Game is the front end which knows about rich text box controls etc and Engine is your logic layer which prob only knows about strings and ints etc

Comment: The "circular dependency" issue sounds as if your `Engine` and your `Game` namespaces are not just different namespaces, but the code is actually in different assemblies/different projects? If so, you should point that out in your question.

Comment: presumably you have an Update() method somewhere which runs every tick of the game? in here do if( Engine.IsDead(X,Y)) {Game.rtb = "i am dead";}

Comment: In any case, I'm surprised there are not more errors in your code that you could fix first. For example, it's not a "NameSpace", the C# keyword is `namespace`, completely in lower case.

Comment: Also this is not valid `Game.rtbMessages += String.Format("You have killed {0}.{1}", name, Environment.NewLine);`

You are trying to use the += operator with a type `String` and a type of `RichTextBox`

Should be `Game.rtbMessages.Text += String.Format("You have killed {0}.{1}", name, Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: 1) A `namespace` has only one effect: to group types and other namespaces; it does not in any way affect accessibility of members between types. 2) Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to improve your question so that it makes sense and is answerable.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper, Yes, they're actually in different projects. Like I said, I'm new to C# and OOP, so I didn't realize this made a difference. If I were to put them into the same project would that possibly solve the problem?

Comment: @Ewan, actually no. This is an incredibly simple game run entirely by button press events. I know using an update timer would probably be easier, but I didn't originally code it that way and didn't want to redo it to include a timer.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi, actually that's how it's written in my project code. I've fixed it here in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you need to rename the class name `Game`. It is same as the namespace name.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Okay the problem is that it's in separate projects. Is there any way to reference the "Game" project from within "Engine" without creating a circular dependency?

Answer (score 2):

Dependancies (project references) should only be one-way.  In fact VS tries very hard to make it impossible for you to create circular references, as you have found out.

Typically, a "Game" project will reference the "Engine" project.  Not the other way around.  An engine should never need to know about types in the game project.

If the engine *does* need to know about a game type then something is wrong with the architecture.  Either the game type should actually be an engine type, or the functionality that you are coding into the engine is game-specific and should be in the game project.

In your case the functionality (updating the rtbMessages control) belongs in the game project.  So from the game code you should do something like this:

```
if (Engine.Monster.IsDead("monster name", monster_hp)) {
    Game.rtbMessages.Text += String.Format("You have killed {0}.{1}", name, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

and remove the `rtbMessages` update from the `Monster.IsDead` function.

Additionally I would consider making another change.
Do you really need `Monster.IsDead` to be static?  Presumably you have a reference to the monster already.  A non-static `IsDead` method on the `Engine.Monster` type might make more sense.  You could even make it a read-only property of the `Engine.Monster` class.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I now understand why this is a good thing though. Seems I'm going to have to rethink a few things in that case, but at least now I now why.

Thank you all for the help, especially on such a newbie question.

Comment: Actually, after some rearranging, it turns out I didn't need `Engine.Monster.IsDead` at all. Thanks for the suggestion of making it a read-only property though, I was going to code it that way before I realized I didn't need it.